# Проблема с чат ботом , Callback api VK

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, callback, бот

Всем привет, пишу сейчас чат-бота для ВК.
Возникла проблема с пересылкой фотографий.
Вот допустим, юзер кидает фотку в чат, а бот пересылает ее другому юзеру.
Запрос бота при отправке такой:

```
{"type":"message_new","object":{"date":1541772226,"from_id":515748911,"id":1586,"out":0,"peer_id":515748911,"text":"","conversation_message_id":371,"fwd_messages":[],"important":false,"random_id":0,"attachments":[{"type":"photo","photo":{"id":456239024,"album_id":-7,"owner_id":515748911,"sizes":[{"type":"m","url":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c850724\/v850724663\/3e36e\/dPbSjy59_BM.jpg","width":130,"height":97},{"type":"o","url":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c850724\/v850724663\/3e373\/7Lks-XZ9ROY.jpg","width":130,"height":98},{"type":"p","url":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c850724\/v850724663\/3e374\/-QOqdUabCUc.jpg","width":200,"height":150},{"type":"q","url":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c850724\/v850724663\/3e375\/fZk3o3VPY_c.jpg","width":320,"height":240},{"type":"r","url":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c850724\/v850724663\/3e376\/OXRSuP3Gl6c.jpg","width":510,"height":383},{"type":"s","url":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c850724\/v850724663\/3e36d\/wSGIBiVpl4E.jpg","width":75,"height":56},{"type":"w","url":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c850724\/v850724663\/3e372\/LVHf34nZKbI.jpg","width":2048,"height":1536},{"type":"x","url":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c850724\/v850724663\/3e36f\/-qTq88DLk3I.jpg","width":604,"height":453},{"type":"y","url":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c850724\/v850724663\/3e370\/aXoAwx5zmkQ.jpg","width":807,"height":605},{"type":"z","url":"https:\/\/pp.userapi.com\/c850724\/v850724663\/3e371\/SYgSSqGFpio.jpg","width":1280,"height":960}],"text":"","date":1541622877,"post_id":2,"access_key":"fdf818b8a9719e5fc2"}}],"is_hidden":false},"group_id":173657849}
```

Я вот таким методом, определяю что это фото/видео и достаю id , owner_id и access_key:

```
if(isset($data->object->attachments[0]->type)){
                  $type_attach = $data->object->attachments[0]->type;
                  switch ($type_attach) {
                    case 'photo':
                        $id_photo = $data->object->attachments[0]->photo->id;
                        $owner_id = $data->object->attachments[0]->photo->owner_id;
                        $access_key = $data->object->attachments[0]->photo->access_key;
                        $attachment = "photo{$owner_id}_{$id_photo}_{$access_key}";
                      break;
                    case 'video':
                      $id_video = $data->object->attachments[0]->video->id;
                      $owner_id = $data->object->attachments[0]->video->owner_id;
                      $access_key = $data->object->attachments[0]->video->access_key;

                      $attachment = "video{$owner_id}_{$id_video}_{$access_key}";
                      break;
                    case 'doc':
                    $url_doc = $data->object->attachments[0]->doc->url;
                    $message = "$message \n\n ????Документ: $url_doc";


                    $attachment =null;
                      break;
                    default:
                      $attachment =null;
                      break;
                          }
                  }
```

И создаю переменную attachmnet, если вложения нет, то она null.

И потом отправлю соответственно пользователю:

```
$vk->sendMessage($apponent,"&#128520; Собеседник: \n{$message}",$attachment);
```

Cама функция:

```
 public function sendMessage($sendID,$message,$attachment=null){
    if ($sendID != 0 and $sendID != '0') {
        return $this->request('messages.send',array('message'=>$message, 'peer_id'=>$sendID , 'attachment' => $attachment));
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

И вот сообственно в чем беда.

Не все фотографии/видео пересылаются таким вот способом.

Вот отправляю я например фотку которая у меня есть на странице или видео из общего доступа, все гуд.

Отправляю фотографию которая у меня в сохраненках, она второму юзеру не пересылается, также и не песелылаются фотки, которые я гружу с телефона . Хотя с компа если загружаю, то некоторые пересылаются, некоторые нет, не могу понять, в чем проблема?

Знает может кто? Спасибо.

Comment: Насколько я помню, то правильный параметр `attachments`, а не `attachment`. Если объективно смотреть код, то визуальных проблем не вижу, возможно проблема в другом.

Comment: Нет, правильный параметр именно attachment. С attachments , ничего не работает.

Comment: уже посмотрел документацию, да, моя ошибка. Можете попробовать в технич. поддержку ВК написать.

Comment: Я столкнулся с такой же проблемой. Подскажите Вам удалось решить?